# How to sync-on or sync-off accounts like Google, Facebook etc. in Settings?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, adb

I want to enable/disable synchronization for accounts like Google, Facebook, WeChat etc, like it is done via Settings > Accounts.

- Is there any `adb` command to do that?
- Can we make changes to the respective app's sql database?
- Or is there any way to do it programmatically ?

Using UiAutoamtor is one option but I want to keep it as my last option. As I want to modify 'sync' flag instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to start with 
[SyncStateContract.Helpers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/SyncStateContract.Helpers.html).
But I think that the required permision might really be too invasive for the user